# How to restrict the zoom?

Tags: zooming, dygraphs

I would like to restrict the zoom in a way, that its not possible to zoom deeper than a certain value. E.g. my data dates from days / months down to 15 minutes, so the smallest value I would like to show (and therefore give the user the ability to zoom only this far) would be like showing 4-5 values of those 15minutes intervalls.

I have found the ticker-possibility in another thread, but thats not helping because it doesn´t restrict the ability to zoom. Is there a builtin method that can help me or another way to restrict the zoomfactor ?

Answer (score 2):

```
zoomCallback: function (minDate, maxDate, yRange) {
// Calculate the difference between the values
var difference = maxDate - minDate;
// If difference smaller than 3 hours
if ((difference / 1000 / 60 / 60) < 3) {
    maxDate = new Date(minDate).setMinutes(180);

    g.updateOptions({
        dateWindow: [minDate, maxDate]
    });

     }
 },
```

Thats what i come up with and it actually works ok so far. I will have to tweak the values a bit but it works like i want for the most part. There is just one Problem with that solution:
When i zoom in, it automatically changes the values and you can see for a very short time that the old values are rendered and then it changes to the new ones. That just doesnt feel that great for the user experience but its not a dealbreaker.
Is there another event that is triggered earlier?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in support for this. But you could define a [zoomCallback](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#zoomCallback). This could call [xAxisRange](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#xAxisRange) to determine whether the new zoom window is acceptable. If not, you could call `updateOptions({dateWindow: ...})` with some acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I found a testcase on dygraphs website called zoom that restricts zoom to a range between mindate and maxdate. [Here is the link](http://dygraphs.com/tests/zoom.html) 
You could build a minimum range out of it, so user always sees at least 4-5 data points.